# How to select Related product random collection Magento 2.1.2

Tags: magento2, related-products

How to get a random collection of related products, using the below code,

```
protected function _prepareData() 
{
    $product = $this->_coreRegistry->registry('product');
   /* @var $product \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product */

   $this->_itemCollection = $product->getAlsoboughtProductCollection()->addAttributeToSelect(
        'required_options'
    )->setPositionOrder()->setPageSize(3)->addStoreFilter();
    $this->_itemCollection->getSelect()->order('rand()');
    if ($this->moduleManager->isEnabled('Magento_Checkout')) {
        $this->_addProductAttributesAndPrices($this->_itemCollection);
    }
    $this->_itemCollection->setVisibility($this->_catalogProductVisibility->getVisibleInCatalogIds());

    $this->_itemCollection->load();

    foreach ($this->_itemCollection as $product) {
        $product->setDoNotUseCategoryId(true);
    }
    return $this;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with this line,

```
$this->_itemCollection->getSelect()->orderRand();
```

Comment: Sorry, No change still getting the same result

Comment: Have you clear cache? remove var folder and check.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
$products = $this
        ->getCategory($id)
        ->getProductCollection()
        ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
        ->setPageSize(3);

$products->getSelect()->orderRand();

$products = $products->getItems();
```